# Bing Maps pushpins not appearing

Tags: c#, asp.net, bing-maps

I wish to add Bing Maps pushpins from the server side. I tried the code below but the pushpins does not appear. Are there any suggestions on how to improve the code below and make this work?

I'm using asp.net and C# for the program below with Bing Maps Ajax Control V7.0

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetLocation(sender,e);
}

protected void GetLocation(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable tblLocation = new DataTable();
    string query = "SELECT Latitude, Longitude FROM Location ";
    if (textbox1.Text != "")
    {
        textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text) + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        textbox1.Text = "1";
    }
    query += " WHERE num = " + textbox1.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    adapter.Fill(tblLocation);
    conn.Close();

    if (tblLocation.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        longitude.Text = tblLocation.Rows[0]["Longitude"].ToString();
        latitude.Text = tblLocation.Rows[0]["Latitude"].ToString();
        string script = "UpdatePushPin( + " + latitude.Text + " , " + longitude.Text + ");";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Key", script, true);
    }
    else
    {
        textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text) - 1);
    }
}
```

Asp.net:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var map;
    function GetMap() {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"),
            {credentials: "mycredentials",
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(12.2, 103.7),
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
            zoom: 12
        });
    }
    function UpdatePushPin(x, y) {
        map.entities.clear();
        var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(x, y));
        map.entities.push(pushpin);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the id of your latitude and longitude elements are different due to ASP.NET adding on info to them. If you inspect the generated HTML you will likely see that ID's are not simply 'latitude' or 'longitude' but more likely something like ctl00$MainContent$longitude. To fix this you can pass the ClientID of your ASP.NET controls into the script you are generating like this:

```
string script = string.Format(@"
<script type='text/javascript'>
function updatePushPin() {
map.entities.clear();
map.setView({zoom: 12, center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(document.getElementById('{0}').text, document.getElementById('{1}').text)});

var center = map.getCenter();
var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(center);
map.entities.push(pin);

}
</script>", latitude.ClientID, longitude.ClientID);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I suspected that as well so I changed my code. I tried yours as well but it does not work. Above is my edited code.